# GLP mass to volume conversion problem (Rotary Meter)

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

this is my first post here on this forum.
I would like to share a question that is bothering me:

I have a gas powered system.
I would like to measure the total gas consumption in `kg`.
The problem is that the meter I use gives me the value in `m³`.
I use the g10 DN40 threaded delta meter from the link below.
It is a rotary principle meter.

https://www.itron.com/-/media/feature/products/documents/brochure/delta-en-web.pdf

Currently I use the factor of `2.5kg/m³` for the conversion.

The system is periodically supplied with lpg gas and the supplier gives me an invoice with the total value of gas supplied in `kg`.

When adding up the total supply carried out in the cylinders within a period of a few months and comparing with the consumption measured by the meter, in the same period, I always obtain lower consumption values. Could it be that the company is supplying me with less gas than it says.

Note: The gas meter is not right after the cylinders.
he is after a few meters of pipes and after a pressure reducer.

Do I need to do a temperature and pressure compensation to get another conversion factor from `kg` to `m³`?

Comment: Maybe - but you're looking at conservation of mass, so my inclination is that your conversion factor is not quite right because you certainly don't have the value for pure propane or butane. Have a look [here](https://www.elgas.com.au/blog/389-lpg-conversions-kg-litres-mj-kwh-and-m3) for conversion factors and report back.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt
The conversion factor that is on the website is a lower value (1.8315 kg/m³ ) than the conversion factor I use, it would make the measurement worse.